# LINQ on datatable to sum multiple columns vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview, datatable, sum

Does anyone know if it is possible to sum multiple columns of a datatable or datagridview, based on a given criteria for another column? in short I have a table that looks (simply) like this:

```
Ph Length  Start
A     10     1.5
B     14     2
C     9      1.8
A     11     1.4
```

and so on....

What I would like to do is understand is, is it possible to use LINQ to sum based on the "Ph" for both the length and Start columns in one query? Or do I need to write one for each letter?

Essentially the result would need to be A = 21, 2.9. B = 14, 2. C = 9, 1.8

I am stumped here and I honestly have no idea how to do this. I do not even mind if someone could point me to a really good resource for learning LINQ better.

Comment: People will be much more receptive to answering your question if you take a shot at answering it yourself and show what you've done / what's failing. In general, for this question, you will want to GroupBy Ph and Sum on the other 2 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine rows in LINQ based on key column values, you use `GroupBy`.

Once you have the rows groups, you can sum the columns of interest.

In LINQ Query Comprehension syntax,

```
Dim sums = From dr In dt.AsEnumerable()
           Group dr By Ph = dr.Field(Of String)("Ph") Into drg = Group
           Select New With {
               .Ph = Ph,
               .LengthSum = drg.Sum(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of int)("Length")),
               .StartSum = drg.Sum(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of Double)("Start"))
           }
```

If you prefer lambda syntax,

```
Dim sums2 = dt.AsEnumerable() _
              .GroupBy(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of String)("Ph")) _
              .Select(Function(drg) New With {
                  .Ph = drg.Key,
                  .LengthSum = drg.Sum(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of Integer)("Length")),
                  .StartSum = drg.Sum(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of Double)("Start"))
              })
```

In both cases, the result of the query is an `IEnumerable` of the anonymous object I created in the `select` / `Select`. You could create a class, or with some extra work, create a new `DataTable` to hold the answer, or use a clone of the existing `DataTable`.